# .NET 4.0 Cannot resolve reference to System.Web.Extensions assembly

Tags: .net, visual-studio, assemblies

I'm trying to import System.Web.Script.Serialization so I can deserialize JSON, but in my Imports statement, Visual Studio can't find the System.Web.Extensions assembly.

Before you dismiss this, I have already made sure I am not using .NET 4.0 Client, and have tried to reference the assembly through the Reference Manager,  through the Properties window, and by dragging and dropping the file directly to the Bin folder, then attempting to reference it. I still get the following error.

[image: error]

I have already checked to make sure I'm in .NET 4.0 and **not** 4.0 Client

[image: framework 4.0]

And the assembly shows up in my References

[image: references]

It also shows up in my web.config file

[image: web config]

and in my file system at the same location it shows in the References dialog

[image: file system]

When I go to "Add Reference" > "Assemblies" > "Framework" (it's targeting .NET 4.0) and click on System.Web.Extensions the dialog closes as if it has completed the action, but if I go back in, it's still not checked.

[image: reference manager]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I tried a bunch of stuff: reinstalling VS2012, removing all references and re-adding them, changing the physical location of the file, and nothing worked. As it turns out, **even though VS2012 claimed it couldn't find the assembly, it still works when being built and executed.** I'm still not sure why VS2012 doesn't like only that particular assembly, but at this point, I'll chock it up to a random error and report it to Microsoft.