# RegisteredObject could not be found

Tags: .net, dependency-injection

I am creating my own IoC for a  Dependency Injection solution for a test project. I can't resolve the RegisteredObject class even though it exists in the System.Web assembly in the .NET 4.0.
1. I cannot change the version of the Framework I am using.
2. I cannot create a dependency on a third-party dependency injection solution.

I checked this StackOverflow article: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28077469/net-4-0-cannot-resolve-reference-to-system-web-extensions-assembly) but the article did not have a good solution.

Error message when trying to build solution is:
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'RegisteredObject' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. **unclear what you're asking**. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Please show a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And btw, using your customly built DI Container is a bad idea. Either use one of the available third-party containers or apply [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/).

Comment: The error message I get when I try to build my solution is **Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'RegisteredObject' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you have to implement your own RegisteredObject class when implementing your own IoC Dependency Injection container. This is not an option for us because the end result will be the Test Dept having to change the Global.asax.cs in the code we're testing so that the Controllers are created by my IoC and therefore I am undoing it. See article link for more detailed information.
[Link](https://timross.wordpress.com/2010/01/21/creating-a-simple-ioc-container/)